# How to set header for tabitem, when items adding through xaml views in tabcontrol WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I am adding 5 XAML views (i.e. UserControls) to the Tab Control WPF. The corresponding tab items for each `UserControl` has rendered as expected. But I wonder how to set header for those tab items. Is there any way? **Note**: I dont want to add tab items directly to a `TabControl`.

My UserControl:

```
public class TimeConsumingView : UserControl
{
    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Header.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Header",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(TimeConsumingView),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(
                "",
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHeaderChanged)));
}
```

My Shell view:

```
 <TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
     <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"  x:Name="grid" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
     <!--<local:GeneralView Header="General"/>-->
     <local:TimeConsumingView Header="2006 - 2007"/>
     <local:TimeConsumingView Header="2007 - 2008"/>
 </TabControl>
```

In this case, the header not bound to the `TextBlock`. When seen from Snoop, it seems the `DataContext` cannot traverse after the `ContentPresenter` of `TabItem` Header.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you want to wrap your items in a `TabItem`?

WPF does that anyways when it renders, which I suspect is your problem because the Header is null by default, so the `ItemTemplate` has a `null` DataContext (You can verify this with [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/))

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"  x:Name="grid" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <!--<local:GeneralView Header="General"/>-->
    <TabItem Header="2006 - 2007">
        <local:TimeConsumingView Header="2006 - 2007"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="2007 - 2008">
        <local:TimeConsumingView Header="2007 - 2008"/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

If you really insist on not using a TabItem wrapper (which WPF will insert by default), use a TabItem Style which will set the Header property

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I handle this by having a String in my ViewModel that contains the name of the Tabitem. I then simply bind to that String using XAML Bindings.

```
<TabControl
        ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}" 
        SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentPage, Mode=TwoWay}" 
        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedWorkspace, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Inside my ViewModel for the Tab I have a property called Header.

```
public String Header { get; set; }

public MyConstructor()
{
     Header = "Name of Tab";
}
```

An alternative solution would be to override ToString().

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Name of my Tab";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You mean the Workspaces collection contains usercontrols or business objects?

Comment: In my example I use MVVM, so it's the ViewModel. You could probably do the same, but keep the String Header { get; set; } inside your actual UserControl. If you need more help, feel free to post the code you currently have.

Comment: My UserControl,
   
public class TimeConsumingView : UserControl
{

        public string Header
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
            set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Header.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(TimeConsumingView), new UIPropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnHeaderChanged)));

}

Comment: My Shell view,


     <TabControl x:Name="TabControl">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"  x:Name="grid" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
               
                <local:TimeConsumingView Header="2006 - 2007"/>
                <local:TimeConsumingView Header="2007 - 2008"/>
           
            </TabControl>

Comment: In this case, the header not bound to the textblock. When seen from Snoop, it seems the DataContext cannot traverse after the ContentPresenter of TabItem Header.

Comment: It's much better if you update from original question with the code, since it's very difficult to read as a comment.